# Posting FROM Node's hosted router to a remote API (not TO Node's hosted API)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

**Wanting a Node router that POST Json to some remote API?**

I put a lot of effort into this issue this morning so I wanted to share this by offering some comprehensive examples for your benefit.

In each example the router has a GET method that when called, POSTS back to the same router.  I'm also showing, very clearly, how to send AND how to access the received data.

In Node.js, in a router, you might sometime what to post from the router to some remote api.

--- using `npm install needle -save` --- the file `routes/nee.js` ---

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var needle = require('needle');

router.get('/', function (req, resp) {
    var dat = { theGreatest: 'ChuckBerry' };
    var lookbackURL = 'http://' + req.headers.host + req.baseUrl;
    needle.post(lookbackURL, dat, { json: true });
    resp.redirect('/');
});


router.post('/', function (req, resp, next) {
    console.log('body.theGreatest', req.body.theGreatest);
    resp.sendStatus(200);
});


module.exports = router;
```

--- using `npm install request -save` --- the file `routes/req.js` ---

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var request = require('request');

router.get('/', function (req, resp) {
    var dat = { theGreatest: 'ChuckBerry' };
    var lookbackURL = 'http://' + req.headers.host + req.baseUrl;
    request.post(lookbackURL, { json: dat });
    resp.redirect('/');
});


router.post('/', function (req, resp, next) {
    console.log('body.theGreatest', req.body.theGreatest);
    resp.sendStatus(200);
});


module.exports = router;
```

--- using Node's very own `http.request()` -- the file `routes/nodehttp.js` ---

--- When you only want to POST some Json data make your life simpler by instead doing a PUT of the `content-type=application/json` -----

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var http = require('http');

router.get('/', function (req, resp) {

    var hst = req.headers.host.split(':');
    var dat = { theGreatest: 'ChuckBerry' };
    var bdy = JSON.stringify(dat);  // you have to take care of this for yourself
    var options = { host: hst[0], port: hst[1], path: req.baseUrl, method: 'PUT'  //PUT!
        , headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };

    var r = http.request(options);
    r.write(bdy);
    r.end();
    resp.sendStatus(200);
});


router.put('/', function (req, resp) { // PUT. it's a PUT not a POST
    console.log('body[\'theGreatest\']', req.body['theGreatest']); // But here you DON'T have to parse it for yourself.
                 // ^ I'm happy for that even if I am feeling the loss of symmetry.
                 // ^^ At the same this is why your life is easier in a PUT instead of a POST.
    resp.sendStatus(200);
});


module.exports = router;
```

**And perhaps the easiest of all**

--- using `npm install requestify -save` --- the file `routes/rify.js` ---

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var requestify = require('requestify');

router.get('/', function (req, resp) {
    var lookbackURL = 'http://' + req.headers.host + req.baseUrl;
    requestify.post(lookbackURL, {
        theGreatest: 'ChuckBerry'
    })
    .then(function (res) {
        //res.getBody(); // JSON parsed or XML object
        //res.body; // or get the raw
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});


router.post('/', function (req, resp, next) {
    console.log('body.theGreatest', req.body.theGreatest);
    resp.sendStatus(200);
});


module.exports = router;
```

Enjoy & I hope these more comprehensive demonstrations help you too.

Comment: none of this fits the Question/Answer format structure of this site as outlined in [help]

Comment: It's nice you want to share the knowledge, but this is not the right place for that.

Comment: While I agree there is a lot of material on this site that needs this kind of attention, clarity, and help

Comment: While StackOverflow is perhaps the most important repository for its prevalence and search-ability / find-ability where else are you going to place it and be of as much potential help?

Answer (score -1):

Looks good.  Quite a bit of effort documenting the different options.

A little later I'm going to add a Requestify.js example.  Stay tuned and look for it above