# Neither Node.js PUT or POST routes are presenting the data that is being received

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried this with a number of different modules and methods.
Even by proving the other modules do work as expected in Node by building a separate test project and testing each module individually.

[Posting FROM Node's hosted router to a remote API (not TO Node's hosted API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161753/posting-from-nodes-hosted-router-to-a-remote-api-not-to-nodes-hosted-api)

This problem is not one of SENDING data to an API.  It must IMO a problem in the receiving API's not giving up the data it IS receiving for some reason.

I've proven the PUT or POST calls are sending the data by sending the call to http://httpbin/org.  That site shows me I'm sending what I expect to be sending.

Here is how I'm sending.  I can even see in the receiving API that that API is certainly getting called successfully.

-- sending --  ((Again.  This shows my node.http attempt.  But I get the same problem using requestjs, requestifyjs, needlejs))

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

    var hst = req.headers.host.split(':');
    var lookbackURL = 'https://' + req.headers.host + req.baseUrl;
    lookbackURL = 'http"httpbin.org/put';
    var dat = {
        what: 'ever'
        , try: 'again'
    };
    var bdy = JSON.stringify(dat);
    var options = {
        host: hst[0], port: hst[1], path: req.baseUrl, method: 'PUT'
        , headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };

    var r = nodeHttp.request(options); r.write(bdy); r.end();
    res.sendStatus(200);

});
```

-- receiving --

```
router.put('/', function (req, res, next) {
    console.log('r', req);
});
```

No matter what module or method I use, in all cases, the receiving `req` object doesn't contain the `what` or `try` data.

BUT in my test project the data is there as I expect it to be, in all cases.
Doing the same `console.log(req);` in the test project, reqestjs, requestjs, needlejs, node.http all show a proper body object.
But in this problem there isn't a body object in `req`.
And sending this put/post to http://httpbin.org I can see the body object is being sent.

**Any ideas?**

Comment: Maybe because try is a reserved Word. Use an other variable name

Comment: @Incognito no. sorry.  I change that because you asked.  Still the same problem.

Comment: You had to change that because it created a compil error

Comment: No.  No compile or run-time errors

Comment: Could you try to narrow your question and be more precise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue found.  And it was something no one on here could have gotten for the code I posted.

For reasons I will not go into I have to take `body-parser` out this application.  This also means app.use() won't have a parser given to it.

And that means I have to deal with getting the data on my own.  So I've added a req.on('data') listener to read the chunk from the call to the API.

```
router.put('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var data = '';      
    req.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
        .....
    });
.....
```

I also decided to do this as a PUT using Requestify.
This just goes to show how easy it is to become complacent and forget how things really work; the assumption of `body-parser` (or other things) always being there for instance.  Or what it is really doing for you.

**NEXT I have to figure out how to get a value out of the `req.on('data) back to the method PUTting to the API.**  Any tips?  Appreciated.